# What factors might prevent this symlink from working as intended?

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

I'm on a Windows 7 64-bit machine, and I've been trying to get a symlink set up to some rather hefty files so that I don't need to use twice the memory (two different applications need to access these files, and neither will permit changing the necessary path to get to them).

This is what I typed into command prompt (which I ran as administrator):

```
mklink /D "steamapps\example\team fortress 2\tf\materials" "steamapps\common\Team Fortress 2\tf\custom\hammer\materials"
```

I got the following response:

```
symbolic link created for steamapps\example\team fortress 2\tf\materials <<===>>
                          steamapps\common\Team Fortress 2\tf\custom\hammer\materials
```

However, when I navigate to the link in my file browser, I get an error:

D:\Steam\steamapps\example\team fortress 2\tf\materials refers to a location that is unavailable. It could be on a hard drive on this computer, or on a network. Check to make sure that the disk is properly inserted, or that you are connected to the Internet or your network, and then try again. If it still cannot be located, the information might have been moved to a different location.

When I try to use the application, the files (which would normally appear in a material browser) are missing.

Any clues as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the full path to the target instead of the relative path you have posted. it may also be useful to drop the case on the /d switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you give to `mklink` is stored in the symlink *verbatim* – if you give a relative link, it will be relative *to the symlink*, not to the current directory.

```
mklink /d "steamapps\example\team fortress 2\tf\materials" ^
          "..\..\..\common\Team Fortress 2\tf\custom\hammer\materials"
```